# How to format columns in a .txt file?

Tags: excel, text, format

I exported a list of data in columns from excel into a .txt file, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get all the columns to line up. Right now, the data looks like this:

```
C5H12N+ 8.609640E+01    1.30E+04    8.6096970E+01   -5.70E-04
C4H11N2+    8.709170E+01    7.20E+02    8.7092215E+01   -5.15E-04
C3H10N3+    8.808690E+01    1.10E+03    8.8087460E+01   -5.60E-04
C5H14N+ 8.811210E+01    2.90E+03    8.8112620E+01   -5.20E-04
C4H13N2+    8.910730E+01    2.30E+02    8.9107865E+01   -5.65E-04
C6H8N+  9.406510E+01    2.70E+02    9.4065670E+01   -5.70E-04
C5H7N2+ 9.506040E+01    1.60E+02    9.5060915E+01   -5.15E-04
```

With the longer chemical formulas, the numbers following don't line up. How can I fix this?

Comment: use appropriate structured formats and software (like excel) text files do not support consistent ways of structuring tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output will not line up nicely in a text file. However, you could try modifying your excel columns before exporting as csv. Are you okay with padding values with spaces?

For example, changing "1.30E+04" to "1.30E+04 spacespacespaceetc"?

Here's a formula that would make each cell 20-width by padding with spaces until reaching 20, and will also trim at 20. Use for every cell.

```
    =LEFT(B2 & REPT(" ",20),20)
```

This is how it would appear in a text editor:

[image]